# curl url is not working in Yii

Tags: php, curl, yii

i am using curl in my yii application first time.

following is my code

```
                       $ch = curl_init();

                        $u='admin';
                        $p='admin123';
                        $postvars = '';
                        foreach($string as $key=>$value) {
                                    $postvars .= $key . "/" . $value . "/";
                                  }

                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  'http://localhost:83/Working-copy/tradiecom/ServiceTypeMaster/Create' );
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $u.':'.$p);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($string));
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);

                        $json = curl_exec($ch);
                        if ($json === false)
                        {
                            echo 'test';
                        }

                        print_r($json);
```

Now i don't know how to access post variables in ServiceTypeMaster/create action??
And i don't know whether my action is called or not? 
How can i know that.

Comment: I only see a curl call? How about Yii part? Define "not working"

Comment: this curl call is part of one function which handle web service response and from there create action called.

Comment: you can create a Component and load it in to Controller, use in Action and save as Variable for Views.

Comment: but i make module 'webservice' which called in web service url. and from this module my controller action called.